# How to get all windows of all applications with GTK4

Tags: c, gtk, gdk

I'd like to get all windows running on a Linux Mint 21.2 XFCE desktop.I am a newbie in GTK. I followed [instruction](https://www.manpagez.com/html/gdk/) and wrote following codes. However, the codes cannot be complied. Appreciated much in advance for your kind help!

**edited on 11th Sep.**
[Stop using GdkScreen](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/migrating-3to4.html#stop-using-gdkscreen)
GdkScreen has been removed from GTK4! Thereafter, how to get all windows of all applications with GTK4? I cannot find a way from GTK website or google or stackoverflow.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <gdk/gdk.h>

static void
func_button1_clicked(GtkWidget *widget,
            gpointer data)
{
  GdkDisplayManager *display_manger = gdk_display_manager_get();
  GSList *displays = gdk_display_manager_list_displays(display_manger);
  while (displays != NULL)
  {
    // Below line is OK.
    GdkDisplay *_display = displays->data;
    // Below line is NG!
    GdkScreen* screen = gdk_display_get_screen(_display, 0);
    // Below line is NG!
    GList* windows = gdk_screen_get_toplevel_windows (screen);
    // Todo. Iterate windows and do something for each window
    g_list_free(windows);
    displays = displays->next;
  }
  g_slist_free(displays);
}
```

Howerver, following error messages were got from vscode terminal.

```
unknown type name ‘GdkScreen’
implicit declaration of function ‘gdk_display_get_screen’; did you mean ‘gdk_display_get_setting’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
```

c_cpp_properties.json is as follows.

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "linux-gcc-x64",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/usr/include/gtk-4.0",
                "/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0",
                "/usr/include/cairo",
                "/usr/include/pango-1.0",
                "/usr/include/harfbuzz",
                "/usr/include/pango-1.0",
                "/usr/include/fribidi",
                "/usr/include/harfbuzz",
                "/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0",
                "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu",
                "/usr/include/cairo",
                "/usr/include/pixman-1",
                "/usr/include/uuid",
                "/usr/include/freetype2",
                "/usr/include/libpng16",
                "/usr/include/graphene-1.0",
                "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/graphene-1.0/include",
                "/usr/include/libmount",
                "/usr/include/blkid",
                "/usr/include/glib-2.0",
                "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "${default}",
            "cppStandard": "${default}",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64",
            "compilerArgs": [
                ""
            ]
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```